# passwd asks for new password 4 times

Tags: linux, passwd

I just had a strange experience. I created a new user on a server (Ubuntu 10.04, Plesk installed) and then wanted to set the password.
Look at that output:

```
# useradd dev
# passwd dev
Enter new password:
Retype new password:
Geben Sie ein neues UNIX-Passwort ein: 
Geben Sie das neue UNIX-Passwort erneut ein:
```

I had to give a password 4 times. The latter 2 prompts are in german.
The password for the latter 2 requests needed to differ from the one given first.
What's going on here?

update:
    # cat /etc/pam.d/passwd
    #
    # The PAM configuration file for the Shadow `passwd' service
    #

```
@include common-password

# cat /etc/pam.d/system-auth
cat: /etc/pam.d/system-auth: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

(/etc/pam.d/system-auth doesn't exist)
Btw. can I somehow set all such output to be english, without changing system locale (which may affect other things)?

update2:

```
# cat /etc/pam.d/common-password 

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
password optional pam_plesk.so try_first_pass
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
password        required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

Looks like Plesk is the culprit. Correct?

Comment: Can you provide `/etc/pam.d/passwd` and `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` if they exist? If they dont exist what distro are you running?

Comment: @Patrick: "Ubuntu 10.04, Plesk installed", as per the question.

Comment: Please provide `/etc/pam.d/common-password` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `passwd` command uses PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules), which ask the user for passwords and update password hashes in `/etc/shadow` and/or any other auth backends you've configured.  PAM for the `passwd` command is configured in `/etc/pam.d/passwd`, which, in your case, merely includes `/etc/pam.d/common-password`.

You can read a quick introduction about PAM with `man 7 pam`.

Now I'm not familiar with Plesk, and I'm still a bit of an amateur when it comes to PAM, but I'd be inclined to swap the first two non-blank, non-comment lines so that `pam_unix` comes before `pam_plesk`:

```
...
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512
password        optional                        pam_plesk.so try_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
...
```

I'll tell you why.  You see that `try_first_pass` option after `pam_plesk`?  It means that if this particular module is being run after a different one, one that already asked for the user's password, then it should try to reuse that password instead of asking again.  However since `pam_plesk` runs first, there's no already-entered password to try, so you get the first two prompts.  And then `pam_unix` runs, and it doesn't have `try_first_pass` either, so you get the other two prompts.

Alternatively you could try adding `try_first_pass` to the `pam_unix` line.

Make a backup of the `common-passwd` file, just in case, so you can rever the changes if they do not work.  I don't have access to Plesk so I cannot test the suggested changes myself.

Comment: For being a pam amateur, you understand it well enough. Everything you said is correct :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my case linux passwd change command asking me to Retype new password twice. Ideally it should be once

So i removed below line from /etc/pam.d/passwd file.
Post that passwd command not asking me to Retype new password twice.

```
 password  required  pam_pwquality.so  retry=5
```

Pre Artifact:

```
 
[root@linuxvmproddbserver ~]# cat /etc/pam.d/passwd
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include      system-auth
account    include      system-auth
password   substack     system-auth
-password   optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so use_authtok
password   substack     postlogin
password  required  pam_pwquality.so  retry=5
```

Post Artifact:

```
 
[root@linuxvmproddbserver ~]# cat /etc/pam.d/passwd
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include      system-auth
account    include      system-auth
password   substack     system-auth
-password   optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so use_authtok
password   substack     postlogin
```